# What do I lose by Ubuntu having no "Tenkeyless 87-key" keyboard model

Tags: keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout

You can see that Ubuntu has no 87-key keyboard models by listing those it does have:

```
localectl list-x11-keymap-models
```

My default keyboard settings file suggests that Ubuntu is using a 107-key layout with my 87-key keyboard.

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

What do I lose by this deficit?

Comment: Is there any key not working as it should?

Comment: That is indeed the question. Are you saying the answer is nothing?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I asked you if all keys on your keyboard are working or if there is any key which doesn't. Only you can answer that.BTW, `pc105` is a 105-key layout.

Comment: It is indeed so that the pc105 keyboard model is a 105-key keyboard model.